# Finding the roots of $x^4+x^3+2x^2+x-109=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, quartics

The given equation is $$x^4+x^3+2x^2+x-109=0$$

I was thinking of using substitution method say $x^4=t^2$, but I wasn't sure what to do for the other terms. Using general quadratic theory we can find sum and product of roots, but I need to find the roots here.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The substitution you suggested won’t help, I don’t think. 109 is a prime number, so the usual factorization techniques will not work. Two of the roots are real, and the other two are complex. You can either use one of the [formulas for quartic roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_equation), or you can use numerical methods.

If you’re feeling lazy, just type your equation into [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Use resultant.

$Res_x(x^4 + x^3 + 2 x^2 + x - 109, A + x^2 + y x)=\\
-(-11881 - 437 A + 216 A^2 + 3 A^3 - A^4 + (-109 + 329 A - A^2 + A^3) y + (218 - 437 A - 2 A^2) y^2 + (-109 + A) y^3 + 109 y^4)\\$

$Res_y(-11881 - 437 A + 216 A^2 + 3 A^3 - A^4 + (-109 + 329 A - A^2 + A^3) y + (218 - 437 A - 2 A^2) y^2 + (-109 + A) y^3 + 109 y^4,-z + (-109 + A) + 4\cdot 109 y)=\\
109(-3943817860179 - 126648656084 A + 71401744702 A^2 + 1078224076 A^3 - 
 332291299 A^4 + (-10360232 + 83547192 A + 872 A^2 + 767368 A^3) z + (308906 - 760820 A - 3494 A^2) z^2 + z^4)\\$

Let linear term of last polynomial equal zero, then

1. get $A$ from cubic equation $-10360232 + 83547192 A + 872 A^2 + 767368 A^3=0$
2. get $z$ from biquadratic $-3943817860179 - 126648656084 A + 71401744702 A^2 + 1078224076 A^3 - 332291299 A^4 + (308906 - 760820 A - 3494 A^2) z^2 + z^4=0$
3. get $y$ from $-z + (-109 + A) + 4\cdot 109 y=0$
4. get $x$ from $A + x^2 + y x=0$